# YOLO...Program doesnt go through the loop to analyze each frame

Tags: java, loops, object-detection, yolo

Recently I am trying to implement an image object detection tool based on YOLO. To start with, I have used the codes [here](https://github.com/suddh123/YOLO-object-detection-in-java/blob/code/yolo.java). Things sounds fine except the fact the program doesnt pass the following line of code (line 72) and will not go into the loop. :

```
                if (cap.read(frame))
```

In other words, if a break point is placed at that line, the program wont go to next step.. Any idea how to fix this?

```
package yoloexample;

import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.dnn.*;
import org.opencv.utils.*;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Yoloexample {

    private static List<String> getOutputNames(Net net) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Integer> outLayers = net.getUnconnectedOutLayers().toList();
        List<String> layersNames = net.getLayerNames();

        outLayers.forEach((item) -> names.add(layersNames.get(item - 1)));//unfold and create R-CNN layers from the loaded YOLO model//
        System.out.println(names);
        return names;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        System.load("\\opencv\\opencv\\build\\java\\x64\\opencv_java420.dll"); // Load the openCV 4.0 dll //
        String modelWeights = "g:\\yolov3.weights"; //Download and load only wights for YOLO , this is obtained from official YOLO site//
        String modelConfiguration = "g:\\yolov3.cfg";//Download and load cfg file for YOLO , can be obtained from official site//
        String filePath = "test.mp4"; //My video  file to be analysed//
        VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(filePath);// Load video using the videocapture method//
        Mat frame = new Mat(); // define a matrix to extract and store pixel info from video//

        //cap.read(frame);
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Video"); // the lines below create a frame to display the resultant video with object detection and localization//
        JLabel vidpanel = new JLabel();
        jframe.setContentPane(vidpanel);
        jframe.setSize(600, 600);
        jframe.setVisible(true);// we instantiate the frame here//

        Net net = Dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights); //OpenCV DNN supports models trained from various frameworks like Caffe and TensorFlow. It also supports various networks architectures based on YOLO//
        //Thread.sleep(5000);

        //Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("D:\\yolo-object-detection\\yolo-object-detection\\images\\soccer.jpg");
        Size sz = new Size(288, 288);

        List<Mat> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> outBlobNames = getOutputNames(net);

        while (true) {

            if (cap.read(frame)) {

                Mat blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 0.00392, sz, new Scalar(0), true, false); // We feed one frame of video into the network at a time, we have to convert the image to a blob. A blob is a pre-processed image that serves as the input.//
                net.setInput(blob);

                net.forward(result, outBlobNames); //Feed forward the model to get output //

           // outBlobNames.forEach(System.out::println);
                // result.forEach(System.out::println);
                float confThreshold = 0.6f; //Insert thresholding beyond which the model will detect objects//
                List<Integer> clsIds = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Float> confs = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Rect> rects = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
                // each row is a candidate detection, the 1st 4 numbers are
                    // [center_x, center_y, width, height], followed by (N-4) class probabilities
                    Mat level = result.get(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < level.rows(); ++j) {
                        Mat row = level.row(j);
                        Mat scores = row.colRange(5, level.cols());
                        Core.MinMaxLocResult mm = Core.minMaxLoc(scores);
                        float confidence = (float) mm.maxVal;
                        Point classIdPoint = mm.maxLoc;
                        if (confidence > confThreshold) {
                            int centerX = (int) (row.get(0, 0)[0] * frame.cols()); //scaling for drawing the bounding boxes//
                            int centerY = (int) (row.get(0, 1)[0] * frame.rows());
                            int width = (int) (row.get(0, 2)[0] * frame.cols());
                            int height = (int) (row.get(0, 3)[0] * frame.rows());
                            int left = centerX - width / 2;
                            int top = centerY - height / 2;

                            clsIds.add((int) classIdPoint.x);
                            confs.add((float) confidence);
                            rects.add(new Rect(left, top, width, height));
                        }
                    }
                }
                float nmsThresh = 0.5f;
                MatOfFloat confidences = new MatOfFloat(Converters.vector_float_to_Mat(confs));
                Rect[] boxesArray = rects.toArray(new Rect[0]);
                MatOfRect boxes = new MatOfRect(boxesArray);
                MatOfInt indices = new MatOfInt();
                Dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThresh, indices); //We draw the bounding boxes for objects here//

                int[] ind = indices.toArray();
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < ind.length; ++i) {
                    int idx = ind[i];
                    Rect box = boxesArray[idx];
                    Imgproc.rectangle(frame, box.tl(), box.br(), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
                //i=j;

                    System.out.println(idx);
                }
           // Imgcodecs.imwrite("D://out.png", image);
                //System.out.println("Image Loaded");
                ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Mat2bufferedImage(frame)); //setting the results into a frame and initializing it //
                vidpanel.setIcon(image);
                vidpanel.repaint();
                System.out.println(j);
                System.out.println("Done");

            }
        }
    }

    private static BufferedImage Mat2bufferedImage(Mat image) {   // The class described here  takes in matrix and renders the video to the frame  //
        MatOfByte bytemat = new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", image, bytemat);
        byte[] bytes = bytemat.toArray();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't pass" the code.

Comment: @DaveNewton As I mentioned in my question, it doesnt go through the loop and program runs liek forever.

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own. So... it's returning false and the loop doesn't break? The code, because it's poorly-indented and deeply-nested, is difficult to read.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree it is horribly formatted. please see my edit (added a well-formatted code)

Comment: @DaveNewton The program doesnt go inside the loop. So it is liek if you add a break poin at that line, the program wont go to next step.

Comment: It cannot *not* go into the loop unless there’s an exception.

Comment: But there is no exception. The program just keep running.

Comment: Then it's going into the loop.

Comment: @DaveNewton The condition doesnt satisfies and it skips the loop but the program doesnt end. I removed the `while(true)` loop and same thing happened.